# AJAX loaded content not displaying (Bug only occurs in iOS/Safari, chrome/Android works fine)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic app set up with 3 tabs (Tab1, Tab2 Tab3) and an ion-list with ion-items in each tab, with different data loaded.

If I open any one of the tabs initially (as in navigating to it from the address bar) they each work. But if I'm on the Home tab and switch to the Search tab, the ion-list doesn't appear. Similarly, if I start on the Search tab and go to the Home tab, the ion-list doesn't appear in the home tab.

The nav bar and tab bar do appear. It just doesn't show the ion-content.

The DOM is infact populated with the data. ion-content contains the ion-list with the ion-items with the HTML and data I want. They just for some reason don't visually appear (elements wit size and width of 0 as if they were empty)

If I resize the Safari window on desktop, the content suddenly appears perfectly.

Also If I start on one tab, switch to another, and then switch back, the content also appears perfectly.

The problem only occurs when testing in Safari on the desktop or in the app on iOS. Testing in Chrome and desktop and running the app on Android run it fine.

If I hardcode sample data and add it to the same array the ng-repeat uses the hardcoded data appears in the DOM correctly. Only when resizing the window or switching tabs makes the rest of the data appear.

The rest of the data is loading using $http.get()

Simple clicking and scrolling appear to not do anything. Only a page resize or switching tab makes the AJAX loaded data appear.

Calling $scope.$apply() or $scope.$digest don't appear to do anything.

The troubleshooting and debugging mentioned above makes me think its a bug with Ionic and/or AngularJS in rendering asynchronously loaded data. I'm wondering if anyone has a solution or work-around to this.

Relevant code:

Controller

```
angular.module('starter.PostListPlaceView', [])

.controller('PostListPlaceViewCtrl', function($scope, $http, PostFactory, Constants, $rootScope, $sce, linkify, SinglePostService, $stateParams, $timeout) {

function sendGetInitialPostsRequest(){  
        $http.get(Constants.GET_POSTS_URL, {params : paramObject})
            .then(function (response){
                $scope.posts = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < response.data.resultsArray.length; i++){
                    var post = new PostFactory(response.data.resultsArray[i]);
                    console.log(post.desc);
                }
                $timeout(function() {
                    $scope.$digest();
                    console.log("$scope.$apply() called.");
                }, 0);

                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');


            });

    }
});
```

Template:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-refresher pulling-text="Pull to refresh" on-refresh="doRefresh()">
    </ion-refresher>
    <ion-list>
        <div ng-repeat="post in posts track by $index">
            <ion-item  class="post wrap" >
                <div class="post-desc" ng-bind="post.desc"></div> 
            </ion-item>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-infinite-scroll on-infinite="getPosts()" distance="1%" ng-if="moreResults &&!loading">
    </ion-infinite-scroll>
</ion-content>
```

As mentioned above, this code works perfectly in Chrome on desktop and Android, so I don't think its a logical/syntax error in my code itself.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by upgrading from Ionic 1.1.1 to Ionic 1.2